# Plotting jqplot points to a chart.js chart

Tags: charts, chart.js, jqplot

I have an API that returns plot points for a jqplot chart, i was wondering if there is any way to change them so they will plug into a chart.js chart?

The string of points returned by the API is similar to the following:

```
[[[1473396905000,1.925],[1473402008000,3.8978],[1473402311000,1.3657],[1473402605000,1.3194],[1473402905000,1.4289],[1473403206000,1.5782],[1473403505000,1.1818],[1473403807000,1.5151],[1473404105000,1.3052],[1473404406000,1.9036],[1473404706000,2.4173],[1473405006000,2.6117],[1473405305000,1.3249],[1473405605000,1.2773],[1473405905000,1.8293],[1473406206000,1.4242],[1473406505000,1.1342],[1473406806000,1.7527],[1473407106000,1.3627],[1473407406000,1.6494],[1473407705000,1.7232],[1473408006000,1.446],[1473408305000,1.5607],[1473408606000,1.5104],[1473408906000,1.4078],[1473409205000,1.5034],[1473409506000,1.8224],[1473409806000,2.2752],[1473410104000,1.0881],[1473410404000,1.509],[1473410705000,1.0817],[1473411005000,1.3751],[1473411305000,1.1361],[1473411606000,1.33],[1473411906000,1.5136],[1473412206000,1.6084],[1473412506000,1.0594],[1473412806000,1.544],[1473413106000,1.7347],[1473413406000,1.3446],[1473413705000,1.4276],[1473414006000,1.6119],[1473414306000,1.1018]]]
```

Any help would be awesome

Comment: May be a dumb question .. But is it an array of datasets with data in `[x, y]` ?

Comment: the first value is a timestamp, the second value is the 'plot point', in essence, yes, first value goes along the bottom, second value plots on the vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small workaround, it is possible to achieve what you want.

You need to use [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins), which let you handle events which occur through all the chart creation (`beforeInit`, `afterUpdate`, `afterDraw` ...) and are easy to implement :

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        // This will be triggered before the chart initalization
    }
});
```

---

Now you just need to populate both the `labels` and the `data` arrays using plugins :

```js
var fromAPI = [[[1473396905000,1.925],[1473402008000,3.8978],[1473402311000,1.3657]]];

Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        // We store the data -- Making it more readable
        var data = chart.config.data;

        // For each dataset in your array ..
        for (var i = 0; i < fromAPI.length; i++) {

            // For each data in your dataset ..
            for (var j = 0; j < fromAPI[i].length; j++) {

                // Populate the `labels` array with the first element
                data.labels[j] = fromAPI[i][j][0];

                // Populate the `data` array of this specific dataset with the 2nd element
                data.datasets[i].data[j] = fromAPI[i][j][1];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can see [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md4xoaLz/) the full code, and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: Thats awesome, just as a side note, if the API threw out another string like so [[[1441584000000,1.0615],[1441670400000,0.6988],[1441929600000,1.2065],[1442016000000,0.7051]],[[1441584000000,2.0407],[1441670400000,0.6988],[1441929600000,1.2065],[1442016000000,0.7644]],[[1441584000000,0.454],[1441670400000,0.6988],[1441929600000,1.2065],[1442016000000,0.6458]]] .... This has dataset for  3 different plot lines. Would the code you wrote be able to handle that as well?

Comment: @BigJobbies Yep it will. You just have to set up the dataset before (adding a second `object` in the `datasets` property of the chart data, and giving it another name, color, etc ..) See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md4xoaLz/1/) with an example. Oh and I suggest you to have the same values in all your datasets for your horizontal axe .. Or else it will be overwriten as in the updated fiddle.

Comment: Yowser, your a rockstar, this is exactly what i need .. Thank you so much for your time and help!! much appreciated

Comment: Hey, sorry to be a pain, but how would i go about looping over the datasets so that it would spit out the right amount if the API was dynamic, if that makes sense

Comment: I don't think I really got it .. But the first `for` loop is for every dataset in your API array. Is it helpful ?

Comment: for instance, if the API only spat out values for one dataset, then in the next request it spits out values for 3 datasets .. The fiddle works only if there is 2, but if its dynamic it breaks

Comment: @BigJobbies You have to clone (*so you need to use jQuery for this*) the existing dataset, each time you need a new one, and before populating the new one. I made [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md4xoaLz/2/) that does it, more or less.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123228/discussion-between-bigjobbies-and-tektiv).